# SQL query from 2 tables (1 is key table)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

PHP

Tables are:

[image]

I have 2 tables, one of trips and the other is key table (index,type)
I want to receive all the names of the trips that the index of the trip type is 1 (output = Alexander)

I receive into variable "$Trip_Type" the user's choice and in addition I need to add to the query another condition of variable $Trip_Population, that has a key table for his values named "Population". How can I combine this in the query?

"Population" is a key table like "Types": 1. index, 2. Type. In addition there is a column "Population_Type" in table Trips. I need all in 1 query

I have this query and I need to add for this the Population condition:

```
$query = "SELECT trips.Trip_Num 
FROM trips JOIN trip_types ON trips.Trip_Type = trip_types.Type 
WHERE trip_types.type = " . $Trip_Type;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: I receive into variable "$Trip_Type" the user's choice. How can I perform the query?

Comment: Would be nice to tell us what language do you use. Now you let us guess if it is php or what... Please edit your question and at least add respective tag

Comment: php. In addition I need to add to the query another condition of variable $Trip_Population, that has a key table for his values named "Population". How can I combine this in the query?  
"Population" is a key table like "Types": 1. index, 2. Type. In addition there is a column "Population_Type" in table Trips. I need all in 1 query

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.name 
from trips t1
inner join types t2 on t1.type =t2.type
```

Comment: I receive into variable "$Trip_Type" the user's choice. How can I perform the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql=
"SELECT t.name 
from trips t
JOIN types ty ON t.type = ty.type
WHERE ty.type = " . $Trip_Type;
```

Comment: I receive into variable "$Trip_Type" the user's choice. How can I perform the query?

Comment: Edited asuming you are using php

Comment: Tnx. In addition I need to add to the query another condition of variable $Trip_Population, that has a key table for his values named "Population". How can I combine this in the query?

Comment: Is "Population" another table?

Comment: "Population" is a key table like "Types": 1. index, 2. Type. In addition there is a column "Population_Type" in table Trips. I need all in 1 query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name 
from trips a
JOIN types b ON t.type = a.type
WHERE b.type ='$Trip_Type'
```

I assume you are use php code to execute this query

Comment: Tnx, using PHP. In addition I need to add to the query another condition of variable $Trip_Population, that has a key table for his values named "Population". How can I combine this in the query?